# AWS API GATEWAY empty body transformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am facing an issue, I cannot succed to solve it after few hour, I am hopping you guys can help :)

I have this AWS lambda function (using python):

[image]

It put item into my dynamodb, when I test directly in lambda it works well

[image]

Here is my dynamodb line

[image]

I created an API with AWS API GATEWAY as a "POST" type, then I set the integration request as followed :

[image]

and Content-Type :  application/json

But when I try to test it on API GATEWAY (or postman etc) I get the following error :

[image]

I noticed that

[image]

But I don't know where the transformation come from neither how to solve it,

Then again, thank you so much for any help !

Comment: Have you set up a mapping template under Integration Request?

Comment: Yes I did, as precised in my post, by  "then I set the integration request as followed :" I meant mapping template, it works when I use "GET" method but not with POST